# Rspec match current url

Tags: rspec

Want to check current url with required one

```
describe "SEO Error" do
    it "URL" do
      visit 'http://localhost:4000/'
      current_path.should == 'http://localhost:4000/'
    end
end
```

Got error like

```
Failure/Error: current_path.should == 'http://localhost:4000/'
   expected: "http://localhost:4000/"
        got: "/" (using ==)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Just encountered the same problem. Solved it for myself like this:

```
expect(current_path).to have_content(expected_path)
```

P.S. Note that significant amount of time has passed since you asked your question and I now use newer version of rspec that uses `expect` instead of `should`

Comment: great answer. I think the `expected_path` and `current_path` should be swapped.

Answer (score 2):

Capybara's `current_path` doesn't return any domain information, per http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session#current_path-instance_method.

Comment: hi mr. @Peter , how can i get the "current_url" of the webpage which i am opening using the Ruby Rspec ? and compare it with the expected url.